# How you identified within app the internet is off or on without using broadcast manager

Tags: android

I'm making android app in which I save location every 10 minutes but when internet off  I save location in internally in android database when internet again on the location is send to server but I used broadcast manager to notified internet is off or on but broadcast message also trigger when the application is closed.

Comment: Why are you don't want to use broadcast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class **InternetConnectivity** and put this code in it.

```
private static InternetConnectivity instance = new InternetConnectivity();
private boolean connected = false;

public static InternetConnectivity getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isOnline(Context context) {
            try {
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
                return connected;
            }
            catch (Exception exception) {
            }
            return connected;
        }
```

then call where you want to check

```
if (InternetConnectivity.getInstance().isOnline(mContext)) {
//your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother it work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

**you can know if internet connection is on or off by this**

```
ConnectivityManager ConnectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = ConnectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected() == true) {

            //Internet Connected

        } else {

            //Internet Disconnected

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectivityManager ConnectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = ConnectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected() == true) {

            //Internet Connected but data flowing not known yet
            //to check data flow use following code
            try {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            //Now you can say that you have active network establishment
        }
        else {
            response = "FAILED"; // See documentation for more info on response handling
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    }

        } else {

            //Internet Disconnected

        }
```